# What are the differences between `setOnMouseMoved` and `onMouseMovedProperty` JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

The action is perform when mouse moved in to the object defined in `group`, coordinates are printed out at which the mouse drops. I found this could be achieved by these two methods:

```
    // method 1:
    group.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.printf("coordinate X: %.2f, coordinate Y: %.2f\n",event.getX(),event.getY());
        }
    });

    // method 2:
    group.onMouseMovedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.printf("coordinate X: %.2f, coordinate Y: %.2f\n",event.getX(),event.getY());
        }
    });
```

Both gave me the expected results. The syntax looks almost the same, I just wondered if there's any difference between those two? When do we use one from the other?

Comment: JavaFX 101. This is the standard for defining javafx properties. The getters and setters are legacy methods to fit the JavaBeans style. You see it all over, not just here.

Comment: Btw, you should be using Java 8 lambdas which makes life damn easier: `group.setOnMouseMoved(evt -> System.out.printf("coordinate X: %.2f, coordinate Y: %.2f\n", evt.getX(), evt.getY()));`

Comment: `onMouseMoved` is a JavaFX property, so the pattern indicates there should be an `onMouseMovedProperty()` method as well as a `getOnMouseMoved()` and a `setOnMouseMoved()` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834215/when-to-use-javafx-properties-setter-and-getter-instead-of-using-the-property-d `setOnMouseMoved(x)` does exactly the same as `onMouseMoved().set(x)`