# Javafx: incompatible types: int cant be converted to IntegerProperty

Tags: java, javafx

link to full project .zip (Inventory System for College) https://www.dropbox.com/s/t88vsjt7awmlv93/MattNapper.zip?dl=0

Trying to get data to show in tableview using ObservableList. Part Model is an abstract. InHousePart, and OutsoucredPart extend Part. Inventory is where I declare ObservableList, fake data, return ObservableList method

In my Inventory class I have:

```
public class Inventory {
    //declaring arrays for parts, and products
    private ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObservableList<Part> allParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();



    //fake data
    //**This is where the error incompatible types: int cant be converted to Integer Property**
    InHousePart part1 = new InHousePart (1, 1, "pick", 10.00, 1, 1, 5 );

    //adds fake data to "allParts" arraylist
    public void addData() {
        allParts.add(part1);
    }

    public ObservableList<Part> getPartData() {
        return allParts;
    }
```

InHousePart Class

```
public class InHousePart extends Part{

    //constructors

    private IntegerProperty machineID;

    public IntegerProperty getMachineID() {
        return machineID;
    }

    public void setMachineID(IntegerProperty machineID) {
        this.machineID = machineID;
    }

    //constructor
    public InHousePart(IntegerProperty machineID, IntegerProperty partID, StringProperty name, DoubleProperty price, IntegerProperty inStock, IntegerProperty min, IntegerProperty max) {
        super(partID, name, price, inStock, min, max);
        this.machineID = machineID;
    }
```

Part Class

```
public abstract class Part  {

    private IntegerProperty partID;
    private StringProperty name;
    private DoubleProperty price;
    private IntegerProperty inStock;
    private IntegerProperty min;
    private IntegerProperty max;

    public IntegerProperty getPartID() {
        return partID;
    }

    public void setPartID(IntegerProperty partID) {
        this.partID = partID;
    }

    public StringProperty getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(StringProperty name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public DoubleProperty getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(DoubleProperty price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public IntegerProperty getInStock() {
        return inStock;
    }

    public void setInStock(IntegerProperty inStock) {
        this.inStock = inStock;
    }

    public IntegerProperty getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(IntegerProperty min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public IntegerProperty getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(IntegerProperty max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    //constructor
    public Part(IntegerProperty partID, StringProperty name, DoubleProperty price, IntegerProperty inStock, IntegerProperty min, IntegerProperty max) {
        this.partID = partID;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.inStock = inStock;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }   
}
```

Comment: do you really expect `1` will be autoboxed to `IntegerProperty`?

Comment: new to the java fx game #beginner

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use JavaFX properties, you should follow the pattern described in the [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107). Basically, a property implemented by an `IntegerProperty` should look just like a JavaBean `int` property in terms of the get/set methods it defines. So your `Part` class should include the following API:

```
public int getPartID() ;
public void setPartID(int partID);
```

Since you're using an observable property to implement these two methods, you should provide access to that property object *as well*, using the method

```
public IntegerProperty partIDProperty();
```

The general pattern is, that for a property with name, say, `prop`, of type `T`, you should have methods

```
public T getProp() ;
public void setProp(T prop) ;
public ObjectProperty<T> propProperty();
```

(when `T` is a primitive type, the return type of the last method will be slightly different).

Also see [When to use JavaFX properties setter and getter, instead of using the property directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834215/when-to-use-javafx-properties-setter-and-getter-instead-of-using-the-property-d) for a similar discussion.

So you should have

```
public class Part {

    private final IntegerProperty partID = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;

    public IntegerProperty partIDProperty() {
        return partID ;
    }

    public final int getPartID() {
        return partIDProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setPartID(int partID) {
        partIDProperty().set(partID);
    }

    // similarly for all other properties

}
```

There is a basic contract here that `getPartID()` should return the same value as `partIDProperty().get()`: making the `get` and `set` methods `final` ensures this is true even if the class is subclassed.

Finally, the constructor should take parameters for the *values*, not for the *properties*. So your constructor should be

```
public Part(int partID, String name, double price, int inStock, int min, int max) {
    setPartID(partID);
    setName(name);
    setPrice(price);
    setInStock(inStock);
    setMin(min);
    setMax(max);
}
```

Note that it is safe to call those set methods from the constructor, because they are `final`. (You could also just do `partIDProperty.set(partID)`, etc., if you wanted.)

Comment: That helped out a lot but im still not getting any data in my HomePage partsTable.